# having trouble creating a form to update a homepage with weekly variables

Tags: php, html

so, I am looking to make my life a little easier by creating a form that allows me, as administrator/creator, to update as group of weekly variables from datalists, without having to manually change the code everytime.

```
 <form  method="post" action="weeklyhome.php" >

 <p>round<input name="round" type="text"></p></br>
 <p>home</p>


<p>game1 :<input  list="teams" name="Game1H" type="text"><input  list="teams" name="Game1A" type="text"><input  list="ground" name="ground1" type="text"><input  list="time" name="time1" type="text"><input  list="wincond" name="wincond1" type="text"></p>

</form>
<input type="button" value="submit">
```

so this would then post to the homepage weeklyhome.php to something like this..

```
 <h1><?php echo "ROUND".$_POST["round"] ?></h1>
  <h2 align="center">Closed Week - Members only/Buy in $25.</h2>

 <td  rowspan="3" align="center">
 <image height="35px" width="35px" src=images\ echo $_POST ["Game1H"].png>  V
 <img height="35px" width="35" src=images\ echo $_POST ["Game1A"].png></br>
    <?php echo $_POST["ground1"].$_POST["time1"]?></br> <?php echo $_POST["wincond1"]?></td>
```

so that the homepage on loading, would see something like this(which is what bi currently have and am changing the code from server manually)

```
   <image height="35px" width="35px" src=images\port.png>  V
 <img height="35px" width="35" src=images\wb.png></br>
  AO </br>WIN</td>
```

and it would take me 2 mins, from anywhere (ie) my phone, to update the weekly round..

any help here would be greatly appreciated..

thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: the problem is form does not seem to be submitting therefore the outputs for the $_POSTvar blank and not showing anything.
everything I have taught myself up to this point in the last 2 months tells me it shold work, and I cant figure out why its not..

Comment: not submitting - cos the submit button is outside the form - see my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a key step. It is not poss to post to the home page (i.e. for the home page to be updated with new data). You cannot change files on the webserver in that manner.

What you can do is to post to a PHP page and have that page store the data on the server, so that the weeklyhome.php page can later retrieve that stored data and display it.

How to store the data? You can save to a file on the server, or you can store to a MySQL database. This is what you must learn to do. It is not trivial, but it ain't that tough either. I suggest taking a tutorial over at [CodeCourse](https://www.codecourse.com/library/lessons/php-pdo-data-objects/introduction) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iq8Z_b56yA&index=3&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEbLm0ErHe7HgEOVIO26R_o) or some other place like [TheNewBoston](http://thenewboston.com/videos.php)

---

[Full tutorial covering most of what you must do](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-amp-mysql-1-installation/)

[Do not store img in database, just the file name as per next link](https://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/)

[Store only the image name in MySQL](https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/903540-how-store-images-database-using-path-filename)

[Storing data into MySQL, retrieving and building HTML](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage)

[Another similar to above](http://www.athena.nitc.ac.in/nitish_b120466cs/files/schema/'MySQLi'%20for%20Beginners%20-%20Codular.pdf)

*Again, take the time to watch the videos. You will thank me later, and I appreciate the thanks.*

Comment: so your suggestion would be to have it post to a separate php, then within that php, open weeklyhome.php and save the variables to the file that way.. I already have a MySQL db running on this page so replicating and editing that table is doable...however the question that remains now iis, can I attach the values brought back by a sql recall the the front of a .png and have the server able to read it as a legitmate image file

Comment: The second PHP would receive the items from the update.php page, and store the items in a MySQL table. Images will be saved to the webserver's file system (look into a plugin called Heyageek jQuery File Upload Plugin) and a record of the image name stored in the table. *Dealing with stored images might involve another tutorial re creating a simple image gallery.* You must re-program the `weeklyhome.php` file to read the database, grab the updated data, and build the page. This should all be part of the `PHP MySQL` tut.

Comment: Okay.. Gotta build another table.. Sigh... If i survive that,  then ill come back and ask about the images as

Comment: if the some of the variables is save are image file names.eg adel.png, rewriting them back into the table like this

    <image src=images\<?php echo $row["Game1H"];?>>

isn't going to output the image right...?

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of time with a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iq8Z_b56yA&index=3&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEbLm0ErHe7HgEOVIO26R_o) but I'll update my answer to post some links so you can see what the code will look like.

Comment: cheers bro...my server provider comes with MySQL v5.5.43 and myPHPadmin v 2.8.0.1

Comment: thanks for the links bro... my server seems not to like mysqli, however it does accept PDO..so I may try figure out how to work in pdo so as to protect from injection, while keeping methods as current as possible

Comment: which truth be told makes absolutely, given the version of MySQL I have at my disposal...throws me an internal server error trying to run a connect from both mysqli_connect and new mysqli

Comment: This is the right place to ask questions like that. Ask tons of questions - we love to answer *(always think in terms of* ***points*** *)* Upvotes are free, so be liberal (but not overly effusive). Don't try to cram five questions into one -- ask five separate questions *but don't ask the same question in two different ways - we'll penalize you for that.* Most views / attempts to help come immediately after asking the question, so don't modify the actual "question" *(edits/clarifications are great)* or add new parts to the question -- accept an answer and ask a new question. *Bon chance!*

Answer (score 1):

The method in the form is `GET` and you are using `POST`and other inputs like 'ground1' and submit are not inside your form so you cannot use them.This might be correct.if that don't work please specify the errors you are seeing in the console.

Comment: it seems not to be posting anything as the outputs are reading blank

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` instead of `type="button"` and place this inside the form

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you want to use `type="button"` you have to write a script to submit the form

Comment: thanks, that has it now getting to and updating some of what I need..it still is allowing the page to read $_POST["team"].png as a recognized file tho